# Доступ к элементам std::map по индексу

Tags: c++, map

Интересует, как можно получить доступ к элементу map'ы с индексом i. Но! К примеру, при перебирании map'ы при помощи итерататора она отсортирована и выводится, к примеру, так (ключи): 50 80 99 111. Мне надо чтобы что-то[i] возвращало значение этого элемента за O(1). Варианты с конвертированием map'ы в вектор не подходят: работает за O(N).

Comment: [схожий вопрос на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7856453/accessing-map-value-by-index)

Comment: Если вы имеете ввиду, что вам нужно за константное время выполнить `operator[](size_t)`, то  для этого лучше подходит `unordered_map`

Comment: Никак. Контейнер map не поддерживает произвольного доступа и ни о каком O(1) не может быть и речи.

Comment: Сортированного контейнера с логарифмическим обновлением и доступом по индексу за константу не существует. Лучшее, что можно сделать - написать свой контейнер с доступом по индексу за логарифм.

Answer (score 0):

Можно написать декартово дерево по неявному ключу и иметь доступ за O(log(N)) и всё те же свойства std::map. В GNU для этого есть контейнеры с k-й порядковой статистикой.